# Woocommerce Upsells CSV - Why Does It Work Only Sometimes?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Just took over data for a large - 150000 product eccommerce site. WordPress w/Woocommerce ans plugins called CSV Import Suite and Better Product Add-ons allow me to upload CSV files with product data. Most things work great but upsells seem to only work sometimes.

Basically, the site uses SKUs and to set up an upsell I provide something like the following:

```
sku,upsell_skus
123,456|543|345
```

This would link the product with SKU `123` to products `456`, `543` and `345`. I would need entries for all 4 products to have thumbnails appear with upsell links on the site.

Anyways. For some reason when I upload the CSVs I get very random results. In other words, sometimes the upsell links show up and sometimes they don't. I thought this might be some kind of caching issue - but in addition to clearing and least the browser and server caches - new upsells often appear right after upload without doing anything.

I have noticed that when I send larger CSVs the results seem to be less great. Small batches seem to take - but this could be coincidental. Also, for some products the upsell_skus list can be 40 or more - although size of list doesn't appear to be a factor in results.

Does anyone have any knowledge or experience dealing with these issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in product [CSV importer](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-CSV-Importer-&-Exporter) instead of a plugin to update the products. The Woocommerce [Product CSV Import Schema](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-CSV-Import-Schema) states that multiple items should be comma separated. In a comma separated CSV file I've done this using a quoted string with either the id or sku to be updated. If referencing an existing product ID, prefix the id with `id:.` If referencing a SKU, no prefix is needed. e.g. id:100, SKU101. I haven't tested it with a large dataset, but I've never had problems using this method.

This is the format for the standard importer csv file

```
SKU, Upsells
123,"456,543,345"
```